# How to restore default keybindings (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, etc) for widgets in SWT?

Tags: java, events, swt, keyboard-shortcuts

When I edit a text field and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then instead of selecting all text in the field, the main menu's handler for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is called.

How to restore the default behaviour, without losing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> accelerator in menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> doesn't do anything on my WinXP workstation using the following snippet. So there is no "default behaviour":

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Snippet22 {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Display display = new Display();
      Shell shell = new Shell(display);
      Text text = new Text(shell, 0);
      text.setText("ASDF");
      text.setSize(64, 32);
      shell.pack();
      shell.open();
      while ( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
         if ( !display.readAndDispatch() ) display.sleep();
      }
      display.dispose();
   }
}
```

If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to work as expected, add such a listener:

```
Listener ctrlAListener = new Listener() {
   public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
      if ( event.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && event.keyCode == 'a' ) {
         ((Text)event.widget).selectAll();
      }
   }
};
```

and add it to every `Text` instance you use:

```
text.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, ctrlAListener);
```