# Ctrl+X working but Ctrl+C not working using Text SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Our application uses org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text as a textfield.

I went through this

[How to restore default keybindings (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, etc) for widgets in SWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143751/how-to-restore-default-keybindings-ctrla-ctrlc-etc-for-widgets-in-swt)

but strangely without attaching any listeners <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> works and copies the relevant text, whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work.I am testing in windows 7 environment.Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Sriram

Comment: Seems to be platform dependent. Ctrl+C, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+V and Ctrl+X are all working without extra `Listener`s on Linux Mint.

Comment: Yeah I want to know whats the default behavior for windows. Any documentation which I can look into?

Comment: The default behavior for Windows is that an SWT text field behaves just like any other text field.  Ctrl-X should *cut* not copy, Ctrl-C should *copy*.  You shouldn't need to do anything to configure this.  Is this not the behavior for you?

Comment: Check this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=97557 or https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=200743